# calculate ratio with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this :

```
id-customer      status     
1                 Won
1                 Won
2                 Won
2                 Won
3                 Not won
```

and I like to add a new columns which is a winrate calculated as : Number of "won" devided by total number grouped by id-customer.

So I should have a dataframe like this :

```
id-customer      status           winrate
1                 Won             1 (2/2)
1                 Won             1  (2/2)
2                 Won             1 (2/2)
2                 Won             1   (2/2)
3                 Not won         0  (0/1)
```

I try like this :

```
df_winrate=df.groupby(['id-customer'],as_index=False)['status'].sum()
```

But it didn't work

Can you help me to calcultate the winrate column please?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` and just calculate the ratio of `sum` over `size` using `transform` to broadcast the results to original size.

```
g = df.status.eq('Won').groupby(df['id-customer'])
g.transform('sum')/g.transform('size')

0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    0.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. "g" is a name of columns or a dataframe?

Comment: I defined `g` in my answer. `g = df.status.eq('Won').groupby(df['id-customer'])`

Answer (score 0):

You should try to group by status and then get group Won and Not Won finally you could create a math equation to pull the ratio.

```
data = df.groupby(['status'])
won = data.get_group('Won')
not_won = data.get_group('Not Won')
```

Be careful with your indexes.. it seems you have duplicates